# new Google Cloud Messaging API

Tags: android, push-notification, broadcastreceiver, google-cloud-messaging

I'm sending a push notification using PHP using curl, and the result seems to return fine:

```
{"multicast_id":2345735671345346,"success":2,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:13456457587969%375ed23445237ecd"},{"message_id":"0:12344526107806%375ed3439fd7ecd"}]}
```

So I'm guessing the message is sent, and the problem is on the `BroadcastReceiver` subclass.

My Broadcast receiver code:

```
package com.example.myexample.pushnotifications;

public class GCMBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
        Log.d(TAG, "onReceive method executed properly");

        //NotificationManager and NotificationCompat.Builder code to build a notification
    }
}
```

then my `AndroidManifest.xml` for the permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" /
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<permission
    android:name="com.example.myexample.pushnotifications.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.myexample.pushnotifications.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

and for the receiver inside the application tag:

```
    <receiver
        android:name="com.example.myexample.pushnotifications.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.example.myexample.pushnotifications" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

The problem is that the broadcast receiver never receives the message.

Comment: Is `com.example.myexample.pushnotifications` the full package name of your Android app?

Comment: com.example.myexample.pushnotifications is where the BroadcastReceiver subclass is located,  but the activities are in com.example.myexample.activities

Comment: But what's the package name declared at the top of the manifest? Is it `com.example.myexample`? If it is, that's the package name you should use in all the GCM related declarations of the manifest (permissions, intent-filter) except of the full class name of the broadcast receiver.

Comment: com.example.myexample is the one declared at the top, should I proceed using it without the "pushnotifications" ?

Comment: Yes, I added an answer with the things you need to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the package of the app is `com.example.myexample`, the following changes are required :

```
<permission
    android:name="com.example.myexample.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.myexample.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    <category android:name="com.example.myexample" />
</intent-filter>
```